# Fatfs detect SD card removal

Tags: c, sd-card, fatfs

I have an Issue with my SD card that, if it is removed it is not detected. (Removed manually). Therefore, when I try and use the SD card I get errors as it is not present.

So I need to detect if the SD card is removed / inserted. If it is inserted then I can re initialise so I can reuse the SD card.

I am using FatFs and programmed in C.

Note my SD card adapter has the following pins with no chip detect:

- CS
- SCK
- MOSI
- MISO
- VCC
- GND

How do I go about detecting this, then uninitialising the SD card. Then when it is re inserted to reinitialise the SD card.

Comment: What is your OS/Hardware ?

Comment: Its running on an arm chip hardware is NRF52840